# How to add the region in city page meta title tag in osclass?

Tags: php, meta-tags, osclass, meta-title

How to add the region in city page meta title tag in osclass?
I want the region to be specified in the meta title tag of the city page in Osclass.
site  url - www.pluzs.com/bangalore-c277405
I tried adding region code in function.php, but the region area shows blank in the meta title tag in the source code of the city page.
If anyone could help to add the region to be shown in the meta title tag?

Comment: With "meta title", do you mean the HTML `title` element?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add a filter to "meta_title_filter".

```
osc_add_filter("meta_title_filter", function ($text) {
    // Do something with $text, search city name and add the region;
    return $text;
});
```

If you have a list of cities, it can be done with a regex. For now, that's all Osclass seem to offer.